# How do you create a Django HttpRequest object with the META fields populated?

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to create an `HttpRequest` object in Django that has all of the `cgi` `META` variables present? I'm attempting to process a view, but can't figure out how to (easily) make the request object. I just want to make sure I'm not making life harder than need be manually copying all the fields from an existing request. This *feels* like something there'd be an existing solution for, but after several hours of searching, I can't find what I need.

I originally went with `Client` and `RequestFactory` from `django.test`, but these fill the request object with junk data, which causes some of the dynamic fields in my view to render with incorrect values (for example, things like `SERVER_NAME`)

Is there a correct way to create a usable HttpRequest object?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by "process" a view? Is this for your own tests?

Answer (score 27):

First, I just want to clarify a couple things in your question:

> I'm attempting to process a view

By "process a view", I think you mean that you want to pass an HttpRequest object into your view's functions. This is usually done through a [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/).

> I just want to make sure I'm not making life harder than need be manually copying all the fields from an existing request.

It sounds like you want to create a new HttpRequest object based on an existing request, particularly without messing with the headers. You should look over the [django.http.HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) documentation to re-use some of the fields from your existing request's fields. For example, `request.META` is a dictionary that can be re-used between request objects.

---

It seems like your best approach is to use the django.http.HttpRequest object directly. You can create it as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
request = HttpRequest()
```

Then you can set the fields however you like, and `request.META` is just an empty dictionary that you can set however you like. For example:

```
request.method = 'GET'
request.META = myOldRequest.META
request.META['SERVER_NAME'] = 'localhost'
```

I can let you look up the rest. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: How can I pass session info to request = HttpRequest()

Comment: setattr(request, 'session', {'key': 'value'}) solve the issue, Is there any better way?

Comment: ```request = HttpRequest()
request.user = get_some_user()
request.session = {} 
```    which was something needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

in case of someone need to parse an Ajax request and call it immediately in some view:

```py
def ajaxRequest(di=None, request=None) -> HttpRequest:
    def is_ajax(self):
        return True
    if request:
        r = request
    else:
        r = HttpRequest()
    r.is_ajax = is_ajax.__get__(r)
    if di:
        for kk, vv in di.items():
            setattr(r, kk, vv)
    return r
```

this allow you to do:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def messageReadPost(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            # ...

@login_required
def chatFriendsView(request):
    # ...
    messageReadPost(ajaxRequest(request=request, di={
        'method': 'POST', 
        'POST': {'other': p.pk}
    }))
```