# How do I transform a python dictionary to an HttpRequest appropriately?

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I have a `builtins.dict` dictionary that looks like this:

```
request = {"data": {"var": "hello", "content": "jello"}}
```

I am writing a test for an API endpoint in django. I am calling the `post` method of that class and sending this request to it, and I am accessing the data in the request using `request.data`. But of course that won't work, because the `request` that goes into my `post` function is actually a `django.http.HttpRequest`, not a `builtins.dict`. How do I make it so that my `request` argument is a `HttpRequest` and not a `dict` so my function can consume it right?

Edit:

Okay, so I have a function that looks like this:

```
class EmailView(APIView):
    """
    Serializes POST data for sending emails.
    """
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        """
        Sends an email using SES
        :param request: POST request
        :return: drf http response
        """

        serializer = EmailSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        args = serializer.data
        send_mail(args.get("subject"), args.get("message"), "info@mycomp.io", args.get("to"), fail_silently=False)
        return Response('Email sent.', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I want to test this function. So, I've written something that looks like this:

```
class EmailTests(APITestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.user = UserProfile.objects.create_user(
            'testuser', email='testuser@test.com', password='testpass')
        self.user.save()

    def init_request(self):
        request = {"data": {"sender": "info@mycomp.io", "to": ["test@gmail.com", "testt@gmail.com"],
                            "subject": "Subject", "message": "Hello"}}

        return request

    def test_incorrect_email(self):
        request = self.init_request()

        reponse = EmailView.post(EmailView, request)
        print(reponse)
```

But, of course, this isn't working because the `request` i'm sending through my to my `post` in the test isn't an actual Request from `rest_framework.request`. Guess I'm saying I have no idea what the right way to write a test for this is... any ideas?

Edit:

My new tests. The EmailView class has not changed.

```
class EmailTests(APITestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.user = UserProfile.objects.create_user(
            'testuser', email='testuser@test.com', password='testpass')
        self.user.save()

    def init_request(self):
        request = {"sender": "info@mycomp.io", "to": ["test@gmail.com", "testt@gmail.com"],
                            "subject": "Subject", "message": "Hello"}

        return request

    def test_incorrect_email(self):
        request = self.init_request()
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        request = factory.post('/v1/send_email/', request)
        view = EmailView()
        reponse = view.post(request)
        print(reponse)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to extract a json body from a `HttpRequest`?

Comment: If so, generally `json.loads(request.body)` will work. `json` comes from the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library.

Comment: @mario_sunny Let me edit my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: You need to show your test. How are you calling the view?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182704/how-do-you-create-a-django-httprequest-object-with-the-meta-fields-populated

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Django REST Framework RequestFactory](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apirequestfactory), eg:

```py
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory

view = EmailView.as_view()
factory = APIRequestFactory()
request = factory.post('/url/to/the/endpoint', {"var": "hello", "content": "jello"})
reponse = view(request)
```

Comment: I am getting an error at the `factory.post('/v1/send_email/', request)` line that says `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_encode_json'`

Comment: Note that since OP is using REST Framework, they will want to use the [`APIRequestFactory`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apirequestfactory) from that library rather than Django's own one.

Comment: @JohnLexus, please check the updated answer, especially how to pass the request to your view, the documentation contains multiple useful examples. If the problem persists, show how `request` looks like

Comment: Sorry for my disappearance. Okay, I did all that, and I updated my question to display this information. I am now getting `serializer = EmailSerializer(data=request.data)`
`AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: As the error says, a request object has no attribute `data`, if what you are looking for is the POST data you need to use `request.POST`